# ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1521,) (1521,1522) ()

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large data-frame `df` where a sample of the frame is:

```
           A       B
0          0    4140
1   0.142857    1071
2          0    1196
3   0.090909    2110
4   0.083333    1926
5   0.166667    1388
6          0    3081
7          0    1149
8          0    1600
9   0.058824    1873
10         0    3960
:          :       :
19         0    4315
20         0    2007
21  0.086957    3323
22  0.166667    1084
23       0.5    2703
24         0    1214
25         0    1955
26         0    6750
27         0    3240
28         0    1437
29         0    1701
```

I am dividing column `A` by column `B` using:

```
df['new_column'] = np.where(df['A'] = 0, 0.0, df['A'].divide(df['B']))*90.0
```

However I am getting an error:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1521,) (1521,1522) ()
```

The shape of column A using `df.A.shape` is `(1521,)`
The shape of column B using `df.B.shape` is `(1521, 1)`

I see that the shapes are different; would changing the shape fix the issue? If so, how do I change the shapes to be the same?

Comment: Try `np.where(df['A'] == 0, 0.0, df['A'].div(df['B']))*90.0
`

Comment: Thanks @WeNYoBen but this leads me to a TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable error.  Do you have any idea on this?

Comment: can you check df.dtypes

Comment: Just curious, why would you want to check for `df.A==0` if you do `df.A.divide(df.B)`?

Answer (score 1):

Your errors looks very similar when mistakenly passing dataframe to `np.where`. Could you check that you pass `df['A']` and '`df['B']`, not `df[['A']]` and '`df[['B']]`. Because passing mixing series and dataframe to np.where` will cause those errors.

**Example**: (I only use part of your sample data, so my `df` has only 11 rows)

```
np.where(df['A'] == 0, 0.0, df[['A']].divide(df['B']))*90.0
```

return error:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (11,) () (11,12)`
```

and:

```
np.where(df['A'] == 0, 0.0, df['A'].divide(df[['B']]))*90.0
```

return error:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Thanks Andy L.  Is there a way to convert the data-frame from df[['A']] and 'df[['B']] to df['A'] and 'df['B']